# Pandas Slicing by given row AND columns indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2),columns=["A","B"], index=["mon","tue","wed","thu"])
df1
          A         B
mon -1.903218   0.084362
tue -0.071207   -1.324411
wed -0.866212   -0.311787
thu -0.267956   0.802968
```

If I do the following slicing operation I get:

```
df1.ix[["mon","tue"],["A","B"]]
           A        B
mon -1.903218   0.084362
tue -0.071207   -1.324411
```

which I suppose was intended but what I was hoping to get was just `[-1.903218, -1.324411]`. i.e. I want combined row and col indices instead of slice the rows and columns seperately.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived with this [-1.903218, -1.324411]. Add another column if that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a [`lookup` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-lookup-method)

```
df1.lookup(["mon", "tue"], ["A", "B"])
Out[42]: array([-1.903218, -1.324411])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
df1.ix[["mon","tue"],["A","B"]]
```

Try:

```
df1['A']['mon']
df1['B']['tue']
```

This will give you:

- the value located at column A, index mon
- the value located at column B, index tue

Based on this, ou can create a function to print the output as you wish.

For example:

```
def locateDay(df, columns, rows):
    #doSomething
    df1[columns[0]][rows[0]]
    df1[columns[1]][rows[1]]
```

Comment: In my specific case I dont write out the names of the columns but derive them from elsewhere. I'm hoping that there is a better way of doing it without even a for loop.

Comment: Maybe there's a faster way to do that... just wait for the pros! I'm not that familiar with Pandas yet...